# Why does JavaScript variable declaration at console results in "undefined" being printed?

Tags: javascript

I have already read the following SO posts:

[Why does this JavaScript code print “undefined” on the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263190/why-does-this-javascript-code-print-undefined-on-the-console)

[Why does Chrome & FireFox console print undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322435/why-does-chrome-firefox-console-print-undefined)

[Why does the JS console return an extra undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270531/why-does-the-js-console-return-an-extra-undefined?)

But none of it explains why the JavaScript console prints **undefined** when I declare a variable as follows:

`var a;`

Comment: Because the variable is not defined??

Comment: Declaration != definition.

Comment: What do you think it *should* print?

Comment: Ok, I now changed the code to (var a = 1;) and still the console is print "undefined".

Comment: No it doesn't http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/72JSf/

Comment: @j08691, [yes, it does](http://jsfiddle.net/HPUXH/). Be sure that you capture the result of the expression, not the value of the variable.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

<del>It prints the result of this expression - which is `undefined`. And yes, `var a` is a valid expression on its own.</del>

Actually, you should rather be amused by why `console` prints `undefined` when you write `var a = 3` or something like this. It also prints `undefined` if `function anyFunctionName() {}` statement is processed. In fact, all the `var` and `function` declaration (!) statements seem to be ignored if there's another statement with some 'real' result:

```
>>> var a = 3;
undefined

>>> var a = 3; a = 4;
4

>>> var a = 3; a = 4; var a = 5; function f() {};
4 // !!!
```

Now, I suppose the real reason behind is behaviour of `eval` statement, as described [**here**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.1):

> - Let `result` be the result of evaluating the program `prog`.
> - If `result.type` is `normal` and its completion value is a `value V`, then return the `value V`.
> - If `result.type` is `normal` and its completion value is `empty`, then return the value `undefined`.

So now the question is, what does `var a = 4` statement *return*? Guess what: it's not 4.

> The production **VariableStatement** : *var VariableDeclarationList;* is
>   evaluated as follows:
>
> - Evaluate VariableDeclarationList.
> - Return (normal, empty, empty).

Now the most interesting part: what happened in the last example, why 4 is the result? That's explained in [this section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-14):

> The production **Program** : *SourceElements* is evaluated as follows:
>
> - Let result be the result of evaluating SourceElements.
>
> [...]
>
> The production *SourceElements* : *SourceElements* *SourceElement* is evaluated as follows:
>
> - Let headResult be the result of evaluating SourceElements.
> - If headResult is an abrupt completion, return headResult.
> - Let tailResult be result of evaluating SourceElement.
> - **If tailResult.value is empty**, let V = headResult.value, otherwise let V = > tailResult.value.
> - Return (tailResult.type, V, tailResult.target)

Both `function f() {}` and `var a = 5` *statements*' return values were `(normal, empty, empty)`. So the script ended up with giving out the result of the first statement (starting from the script's end, so technically it's the last one) that's not `(normal, empty, empty)`. That is the result of `a = 4` assignment statement - which is `4`.

---

P.S. And now for some icing on the cake: consider the following:

```
>>> function f() {}
undefined

>>> (function f() {})
function f() {}
```

The difference is quite subtle: the first input is treated as a `Function Declaration` statement, which, according to this rule...

> The production **SourceElement** : *FunctionDeclaration* is evaluated as
>   follows:
>
> - Return (normal, empty, empty).

... will eventually produce `undefined` when `eval`-ed, as we already know.

The second input, however, is treated as a `Function Expression`, which is evaluated [to the function itself](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.5). That means it'll be passed through `eval` and eventually returned to the console (in its format).

Comment: Why does (var a = 1;) prints "undefined" while (a = 1;) doesn't print anything.  Is the first an expression (which evaluates to undefined) while the second is not even an expression?

Comment: The behavior is not specific to firebug. Chrome console and even node.js prompt prints "undefined" when they encounter variable declaration.

Comment: Correct, changed that. Now looking for the kind of official statement on this.

Comment: @Rajkumar Well, now I think I found an explanation. )

Comment: Added some details about `Function Declaration` statement - I've missed that part in the standard initially, and was wondering why it's not evaluated to the Function itself. But now, when I found the clear description of the difference between that and `Function Expression`, I think the final piece of a puzzle is there. )

Answer (score 8):

```
var a=1;
a
```

gives:

```
1
```

while

```
var a=1;
```

gives:

```
undefined
```

in the first case the console evaluates a so it prints the value of a

in the second case the console does not evaluate the value of a, but it evaluates the expression itself.

Answer (score 3):

because all you are doing is declaring there is a variable - what is it? a string, an integer, a boolean - we don't know yet - hence `undefined`

Comment: Richie: As I have mentioned in other comments, even when I declare as well as define a variable, the console is print "undefined".

Comment: you are DECLARING a vairable - var a = 'hi please put aside some memory for something I am going to store. -> until you give it a value it is 'undefined' because it does not know what it is -> it is a variable - that is a generic name we give to an integer, an array, a boolean - it isn't actually ANYTHING until you give it a type or a value (at which point it works out its type)

Comment: When you type (var a = 1;), at the end of the statement execution, the  variable is assigned a value of 1 but the console still chooses to display "undefined".

Comment: are you typing directly in the console?

Comment: It is console as well as node.js.  And just realized that the variable in my example might have got hoisted and is broken into two separate statements.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you evaluate a line of code, you get a completion type/record `result` which has 3 attributes: `type`, `value` and `target`. According to the [Ecma specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.1##):

> If `result.type` is normal and its completion value is a value `V`, then return the value `V`.

> If `result.type` is normal and its completion value is `empty`, then return the value `undefined`.

It turns out that when you declare a variable or a function, the `completion type` is `(normal,empty,empty)`. Since the `result.type` is `normal` and value is `empty`, it returns the value `undefined`.

However when you type `a = 3`, it's an assignment expression and its completion type is `(normal, GetValue(), empty)`. So you will just see `3` in the console.

For terms around `statement` and `expression`, see [difference statement/expression](https://medium.com/launch-school/javascript-expressions-and-statements-4d32ac9c0e74).

For different values of completion type, see [completion type documentation](https://interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-12.html).

If you check the completion type documentation, you can see that empty statement `;` has also a completion type `(normal, empty, empty)` (so it should return `undefined`), and indeed it's the case. For the same reason, `if (x>3) {console.log(x)}` also returns `undefined` and `do {console.log(3);} while (false)` too.

However, `(function f(){})` doesn't return `undefined` because it's an expression statement.

Test by yourself. Here are some more examples:

```js
eval('function f(){}'); // Return (normal, empty, empty), undefined
eval(';'); // Return (normal, empty, empty), undefined
eval('(function f(){})'); // (normal, GetValue(exprRef), empty), ExpresionStatement
function foo() {
  return 4;
} // Return (normal, empty, empty), undefined
foo(); // (return, 4, empty), 4
eval('function foo() {return 5;}'); // Return (normal, empty, empty), undefined
eval('foo();'); // (return, 4, empty), 4
let x = 4; //  (normal, empty, empty), undefined
if (x > 3) {
  console.log(x);
} //  (normal, empty, empty), undefined
console.log(6); // (normal, empty, empty), undefined
eval('let x = 4; if (x>3) {console.log(x)}'); // undefined
let y = 5; //  (normal, empty, empty), undefined
do {
  console.log(3);
  y++;
} while (y < 8); // this returns y, can you explain why?

do {
  console.log(3);
} while (false); // undefined since (normal, empty, empty)
```