# How do I define a float in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, exponential

So I want to give JS a number in exponential notation.  Amazingly, I haven't found a reference on how to do this.

Why doesn't this work?

```
 var tempdec = 8.85956e-8;
```

I don't have to do

```
 var tempdec = parseFloat('8.95956e-8');
```

...do I?

... answered below.

The upshot: It does work.

However, using `var` in the console returns `undefined`.  But it works nonetheless.

Comment: Remember to end the line in a semicolon.

Comment: It works fine for me. Define "doesn't work".

Comment: Returns 'undefined' in at least the Chrome Dev Tools console.

Comment: Semicolon does not fix it.  But thanks, I'll put in the question.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-prepends-a-line-saying-undefined

Comment: this one even better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844840/why-does-javascript-variable-declaration-at-console-results-in-undefined-being

Answer (score 1):

Numbers in javascript are floating point integers, so you don't have to use `parseFloat('8.95956e-8')` as `8.85956e-8` is same.

Try this in the console:

```
var tempdec = 8.85956e-8;
console.log(tempdec);//It logs 8.85956e-8 not undefined
console.log(parseFloat(tempdec));//Logs the same as above...
```

Comment: Okay... do you have any insight as to my initial question?  Specifically, why `var tempdec = 8.85956e-8;` returns `undefined`?

Comment: @JoshuaPenman Because your line of code doesn't return anything for the console to output. If you enter `tempdec` it will show the value.

Comment: I thought I knew a little about floating point, but I don't know what "floating point integers" are. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: nothing. I wanted to mean numbers...