# undefined thrown when defining var

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, undefined

The next code is interpreted in Google-chrome console:

```
a = 123
123
     % Ok!

var b = 123
undefined
     % `undefined`? why? b is not undefined, it contains `123`.
```

Comment: I believe this question has been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844840/why-does-javascript-variable-declaration-at-console-results-in-undefined-being

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you're doing this in a console that shows you the result of the operation.

The result of an assignment expression is the value that was assigned. But `var` statements don't *have* a result, not least because they don't occur within the usual step-by-step flow of code. We can see this in the definition of the `var` statement in the spec: [§13.3.2.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-variable-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation) tells us that the result of `var` is the abstract specification call `NormalCompletion(empty)`, which is [just an alias](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-normalcompletion) for `Completion{[[type]]: normal, [[value]]: argument, [[target]]:empty}` which is for [indicating how a statement/expression completed](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-completion-record-specification-type). In this case, it completes with no value. (Which isn't true of all JavaScript statements, surprisingly.)

Answer (score 2):

`var` is a statement.  Statements have no value, so `eval()` (which the console calls) returns `undefined`.

`a = 123` is a simple expression, which returns `123` (so that you can write `b = a = 123`).  When passed an expression, `eval()` returns the expression's value.

Comment: Actually, the statement (no pun) "statements have no value" isn't correct for JavaScript (which I was very surprised to learn a few months back). Try this in your console, for instance: `{1, 2, 3}`. The result is `3`, because [the result of a block statement is the value of the last statement within the block](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-block-runtime-semantics-evaluation).