# Assigning function to a variable gives undefined

Tags: javascript

I have some functions assigned to a variable like:

```js
var WEBRTC_PEER_CONNECTION     = ( window.webkitRTCPeerConnection   ||
                                   window.mozRTCPeerConnection      ||
                                   window.RTCPeerConnection         );
```

When I try **WEBRTC_PEER_CONNECTION** in the Browser's console, it gives me ***undefined***. But, when I try the following directly, I get the function:

```
( window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.RTCPeerConnection );
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
function RTCPeerconnection() { code }
```

Why, is it so?

Comment: as an aside, shouldn't you be testing for the unprefixed feature first? If you start with the prefixed versions, eventually - when RTCPeerConnection is available - your app will start spitting out obsoleted warnings until the prefixed versions go away.

Comment: Seems this is how console evaluates expressions.
[Check this stack for a detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844840/why-does-javascript-variable-declaration-at-console-results-in-undefined-being)

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the point in your code where you are assigning `WEBRTC_PEER_CONNECTION`, and verify it is getting set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I believe the `undefined` you are getting is the result of defining a variable.

Try typing just `WEBRTC_PEER_CONNECTION` on the console and you would get the same result.

---

[image: RESULTS]

Comment: WEBRTC_PEER_CONNECTION is defined in a JS file which is already available after window load, I'm not defining it in Browser console. Just trying to access it.

Comment: Oh it that case, could it be that the variable `WEBRTC_PEER_CONNECTION` is in a closure? and you tried accessing it from the browser console?

Comment: No, it's not a closure. It's just defined as a constant (in constants.js), as given in the question.

Comment: have you checked if `contants.js` is being loaded? starting to feel like a troubleshooter, what's the right term?