# Javascript console.log in browser consoles

Tags: browser, console, console.log

all,

I am trying to use Chrome or IE browser consoles to return some simple output like below.

```
var date = new Date(2016, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0);
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date));
```

The consoles return 2/14/2016 which is the expected output, but it also returns 
'undefined' string after the output. 
I don't know what it means and is it recommended to remove or not use 'console.log' when using browser consoles?

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the function

Refer the following So Question:

[Why does JavaScript variable declaration at console results in "undefined" being printed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844840/why-does-javascript-variable-declaration-at-console-results-in-undefined-being)