# Why does this code show `undefined` when pasted into the browser console?

Tags: javascript

I am having issues trying to run a simple function with an array, it runs undefined, but when I console log it I get th right result?

Please can anyone help?

```
var test = (function (newThing){

  newThing = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

  var  myarray = newThing.map(n=>n*n)
    .reduce((a,b)=> {return a+b});

  return myarray;
})();
```

Comment: The console always try to log the return value of any expression. `var x = 1` yields no return value, so it shows `undefined`. Remove `var test =` and you will see the return value in the console.

Comment: I rolled back the edit because running the code in a snippet doesn't replicate the behavior the OP is describing. (My answer is a CW because I'm **sure** there's a duplicate, so I didn't reopen.)

Comment: Duplicate, probably: [Why does JavaScript variable declaration at console results in “undefined” being printed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844840/why-does-javascript-variable-declaration-at-console-results-in-undefined-being)

Comment: @apsillers: Thank you! I knew there was one.

Answer (score 3):

It's because when you paste that code into the console, the console shows the result of the `var` declaration, which is `undefined`. The code is fine, and `test` gets set correctly, it's just the effect of running code starting with `var` in the console.