# Why does the console print undefined when I assign a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey pretty simple task I am trying to do.... I'm trying to take the text in my textbox and assign it to a var. When I run without the var I am getting text but if I assign it to a var I get undefined. Could someone explain this to me as it is very confusing to me?

[image]

Comment: use .val() instead if you are dealing with inputs

Comment: That just returns undefined aswell... I was trying to use that originally

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844840/why-does-javascript-variable-declaration-at-console-results-in-undefined-being

Comment: it's always better to add actual code to your question and not a screenshot of code.  you can add your markup and js to a code snippet to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Per spec, `var` statements return _undefined_ http://es5.github.io/#x12.2 . The identifier `test` will still be initialised and set. Type `test;` and you will see its contents

Comment: But if I try console.log(test) I still get undefined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**: It does not.

You can see content of your variable `test`, il will output the same thing as before. In fact it is the variable assignement that returns the `undefined` you see here.

For instance:

```
var test = 'Hello' // => undefined
test // => 'Hello'
```

Another case is printing your variable with `console.log`. If you do so, the return value will be `undefined` but the output will be your variable content (*Hello* here).

```
console.log(test) // return: undefined / print: Hello
```

Comment: i agree - doing variable assignments in the console usually spits out "undefined".  try logging `test` after declaring it and see what you get

Comment: But if I try console.log(test) I still get undefined?

Answer (score 0):

What's returning `undefined` is the statement itself that you entered into the console, NOT the value of `var text`.

To see that `console.log(text)` or simply type `text` in the console.

[image]

Comment: That is not related to the question OP asked

Comment: So now it’s a duplicate of mine

Comment: But if I try console.log(test) I still get undefined?