# How is the return value of the js object property assigned to the reference address?

Tags: javascript, assignment-operator

```
var o1 = {};
var o2 = { bar: 'hello' };

o1.foo = o2; // in console  {bar: "hello"}
var o3 = o2;// in console  undefined
```

Why is `{bar: "hello"}` being printed?
Why is `undefined` being printed?

Comment: what's code `console` ?

Comment: The reason the console prints `{bar: "hello"}` is because evaluating an assignment expression results in the right-hand operand's value.

Comment: [Why does JavaScript variable declaration at console results in “undefined” being printed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844840)

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't happen - the code creates a new property of `o1` named `foo`, and assigns it the value of `o2`, which is an object - so the property `o1.foo` is an object consisting of `o2`.

```js
var o1 = {};
var o2 = {
  bar: 'hello'
};

o1.foo = o2;

console.log(o1);
```

The reason you see `{ bar: "hello" }` in the console when you copy/paste the code is because the final return value from the code is `{ bar: "hello" }` (from `o1.foo = o2`). `o1` is still an object containing `foo`, but the `{ bar: "hello" }` shown in the console is just the return value from the code.

Comment: [It _does_ happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21f4Y.png).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That's because when you copy/paste the OP's code into the console, the final return value is printed - which is the value assigned to `o1.foo` (which is `o2`). I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Edited @PatrickRoberts.