# What does this 'undefined' mean in the browser's console?

Tags: javascript, variables, console, constants

```
> const a= 1
< undefined
```

When you define a value in the browsers console, you got a message 'undefined'.
What does this 'undefined' mean in the browser's console?
​

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does JavaScript variable declaration at console results in "undefined" being printed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844840/why-does-javascript-variable-declaration-at-console-results-in-undefined-being)

Comment: That's the return value of using the assignment operator. You always get a response by the Javascript Engine when you write an expression of any type. Try to write a function declaration on the console and press enter to see what the Engine returns after declaring that function. The same happens when you write a primitive: If you write the primitive 5 you get back 5 as a response.

Answer (score 0):

That the expression does not produce a value

```
function doIt(){
    return 1
}
```

undefined

```
doIt()
```

1